# Code not compiling when template functions are placed in a certain order

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

The following program compiles successfully.

```
template<typename T>
T sum(T x) {
    return x;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T sum(T x, Args... args) {
    return x + sum(args...);
    
}

int main() {
    sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

}
```

However, when I switch the order in which the template functions are written, it no longer compiles:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T sum(T x, Args... args) {
    return x + sum(args...);

}

template<typename T>
T sum(T x) {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

}
```

The compiler error I get is:

> error C2780: 'T sum(T,Args...)': expects 2 arguments - 0 provided, message : see declaration of 'sum'

Why does this happen? Aren't both functions already defined prior to being called in main()? Why does the order in which they're written in matter?

Comment: Your single arg `sum` is what terminates the recursion.

Comment: In the non-compiling case, when the first template function is defined there is no other `sum()`, hence it's unambiguous. In the compiling case there are now two `sum()`s, so overload resolution enters the picture. The rules are quite arcane, but that's the capsule summary.

Comment: It is not the question but if you have access to a C++17 compiler you can use folding and implement `sum` as a single function. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M9caYv163

Answer (score 28, accepted):

At the heart of your question is the following issue: when a function name, such as `sum`, appears inside a function template, what function does it refer to?

You wrote:

> Aren't both functions already defined prior to being called in main()? Why does the order in which they're written in matter?

You seem to have the following expectation: that when a function template is *instantiated*, and a function name such as `sum` appears inside it, the compiler finds all overloads of `sum` that have been declared so far. Thus, according to your theory, since the `sum` function template is not instantiated until it is called in `main`, at that point, both overloads of `sum` are visible, so the recursive calls to `sum` should consider both overloads and eventually select the unary one to terminate the recursion.

However, as you've seen, that's not the case. If the variadic `sum` is declared first, it eventually recursively calls itself with a single argument (ignoring the unary `sum` overload declared later), which then attempts to call `sum()` (no arguments), leading to a compilation error.

In this example, it thus appears that when the compiler sees a call to `sum` inside a function template, it only finds functions named `sum` that have been declared at the point of the call. When you switched the order around, you made it so that the variadic `sum` could never call the unary `sum`.

Actually though, the truth is more complicated. The C++ standard requires a behaviour that is colloquially referred to as "two-phase lookup". What this means is:

1. when the compiler sees the definition of the function template, it finds all functions named `sum` that have been declared so far, and
2. when the compiler later instantiates the function template, it uses [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) to find additional overloads of `sum` regardless of whether they were declared before or after the enclosing template.

In your code, `sum` is only ever called with arguments of type `int`, which does not belong to any namespace. Thus, the variadic `sum` only finds itself in phase 1, and nothing in phase 2.